# Avoid a "PHP Strict standards" warning with parentheses?

Tags: php

In the following code, why do the extra parentheses avoid the warning?

> PHP Strict standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference.

```
$lastEl = array_pop((array_slice($array, -1)));
```

Comment: I have the warning even with parentheses (PHP 7.0.5)

Comment: 5.5.9 only warns on the no-parens version. definitely interesting...

Comment: @MarcB: 5.6.5 as well.  Must've been fixed in 7.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/gWGUL